# WP7 in app payment options

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile

We are building a WP7 mobile game that will allow players to purchase game specific items.

Is there any other WP7 in app payment options other then PayPal?  If so, are any of them better?

Thank you.

-Jessy Houle

Comment: It's not really a technical question, so I would say it belongs over at the [AppHub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) more than it does here.

Comment: Did you find a solution since Oct 11 ? if yes, can you please anwser to your question, i'm looking for it too. Thanks

Comment: We ended up going with PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was flicking through old slides from WUPG today in [AdDuplex's slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ailonid/developers-guide-to-windows-phone-app-marketing-and-monetization) and they suggested [Linxter](http://linxter.com/) and [MoVend](http://www.movend.com/). Never tried either of them so dont make any claims about them working on WP7 or being easy.